# Having multiple binaries in the Apple App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there anyway to have multiple binaries in the App Store?

For example, let's say I have an app currently out in the U.S. App Store.

Is there any way for a user, when downloading the application from the Canadian App Store, to retrieve a different binary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible - assuming you're talking about different versions of the same App for different regions, then no.

When you create an application entry in iTunes Connect, you are only able to upload one binary. The Application can (and should) be localised, and you can specify which countries you wish the application to be available in.

That is as far as it goes.

Comment: I figured as much. Was worth a shot. Thanks.